Diode from a controller board identification
I'm facing some trouble identifying the following diode
Diode with three I or 1 all over the sphere face:

There are three I or 1 on sphere face. How to identify?

Look at the schematic diagram -- but without make/model of item, don't expect anyone to be able to find that for you. That said, looks like it might be an  older power rectifier.

Hello, unfortunately the only schematic is a reverse engineering by some guys, there's no part list. I confirm it is an old component, talking about beginning of 90s. Here's the schematic I'm using: https://hico-srv022.pixhotel.fr/sites/default/files/gamoovernet/20130822135915-gc339-ConverBT.GIF, the diode (D4) is up/middle near pin 4 of a L2.

That appears to be a sintered glass SOD-57 or SOD-64 package. This package style is used for a few different types of diode such as rectifiers, zeners, and avalanche diodes.
Not much to go on from the markings but you can narrow it down by how it's used in the circuit. I've seen these in sets of four used as a bridge rectifier, but there could also be two for a full wave or one for a half wave rectifier. It could also be a zener reference in a voltage regulator circuit.
Update: Now that you've posted a schematic we can rule out it being a zener as those are drawn differently. It looks like it might be part of a snubber circuit, so maybe just a plain old rectifier, or maybe fast recovery.

Hello, thank you for your hints, it's a good starting point for investigation. I forgot to mention in the original post that on PCB the component is marked as D4, Zener diode are instead marked as ZD so I can confirm it is a diode. Here there's a more accurate schematic: https://gamoovernet.pixhotel.fr/pics/20210205115231-gc339-ConvBT.PNG. The D4 is upper left. The Q1, if it could help, is coded K1535.
